# Table with questions YES/NO

Tags: tables, multirow

Im writing an important health document on some COVID guidelines and im stuck on this table. I need to make it in latex format, and i cant seem to get it to work. errors and such when i try to make the yes no on the right but still have the form over.[image]

How can i make this?

Comment: Can you provide the tags what you tried till now as `MWE`?

Comment: well i cant make the format for this so all i have done was i found something on google. but nothing simual.

Comment: Try with `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X |*{4}{p{2em}|} }` as table head, and than provide table body. Part, which you not know, how to do it, left to us :-).

Comment: If the problem is about the "Samtale 1"  cell, you can use `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Samtale 1}` for that. If the problem is the "Guiding Question" cell, use `\multirow{2}{*}{Guiding Question}`(rquires the `multirow` package).

Comment: Please clarify what "form over"  in "make the yes no on the right but still have the form over" means. Do you want a table that can be filled in using a pdf viewer? Should the yes/no cells contain checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the below tag may helps you:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Guiding questions:}}
&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Samtale 1} &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Samtale 2}\\
\cline{2-5}
 &JA &NET &JA &NEI\\
\hline
Does this is for test this is for test this is for test & & & &\\
\hline
Has this is for test this is for test this is for test & & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot! :)

Comment: I need this to be on top of it. Can you add that in a suitable way? ```\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
    Name of employee: & \text{$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $} & Signature from nurse:\\ \hline
    Telephone: &  &  \\ \hline
    Place of residence: &  &  \\ \hline
    Travel date: &  &   \\ \hline
    Date of first conversation: &  &   \\ \hline
    Date of second conversation: &  &   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point, with `tabularx` and `eqparbox` (to ensure the last 4 columns have the same, minimal, width):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, cellspace, makecell}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\newcommand{\Comments}{\newline Comments: \newline}


    \begin{document}

{\centering
\sffamily
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setcellgapes{2pt}\makegapedcells
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|*{4}{c|}} %
\hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\centering\textbf{\large Guiding questions:}} & \multicolumn{2}{Sc|}{Samtale 1} & \multicolumn{2}{Sc|}{Samtale 2} \\
\cline{2-5}
 & \eqmakebox[H]{JA} & \eqmakebox[H]{NEI} & \eqmakebox[H]{JA} & \eqmakebox[H]{NEI} \\ \hline%
 Does the employee have respiratory symptoms? \newline
For example: cough, sore throat, breathing difficulties
\Comments & & & & \\ \hline
Has the employee had a fever during the last 7 days?
\Comments & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]